# Does marriage play a role in a person's provision?

Tags: nikah, islamic-philosophy

Does marriage play a role in a person's provision? Can it make you rich or poor?

Comment: You might have better luck if you either did a little research and dug up the hadith and then asked this question, or split this question into two - one asking for the hadith, and the second asking your question here.

Comment: It does enhance provision Inshallah as mentioned in a  hadith , related broader question :http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/7663/940

Comment: @Ali: does it also do the opposite? Bringing bad luck? Decreasing one's Rizq?

Comment: @Noah There is no badluck \ bad omen in Islam only good omens exist. At worst any person except yourself wont be responsible for decrement of rizq.  It wont decrease risq as it comes from Allah swt Alone. Rizq may be increased by Allah swt for those who marry and have many children and dont sleep and goto business after fajr prayers.

Comment: @Ali, maybe Noah used the wrong words. I guess he doesn't mean "bad luck" in terms of omens; rather, just the way a woman opens the doors of rizq for her husband, can the opposite also happen? Another question is, can a man's taqdeer stop the good rizq that a woman brings? These are very relevant questions since I know someone married to a lady who's father became very prosperous after she was born but after her marriage lost everything. However now her husband does not seem to be benefiting from marriage with her. We don't claim to know the ghayb but we can surmise based on the ahadeeth.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

"And marry the unmarried among you and the righteous among your male slaves and female slaves. If they should be poor, Allah will enrich them from His bounty, and Allah is all-Encompassing and Knowing" Surat An-Nūr 24:32 (The Light)

Marriage is really a door opener of sustenance. Otherwise, divorce can making you lose wealth.